# Slideshow Glitch - Debugging Assistance

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wordpress site with an image slider.  At some point the transitions on this image slider became sloppy.  The image slider in question is flexslider.  I tried replacing it with jquery cycle lite, in which case I discovered the same sloppy transition was affecting it as well.  Which confirmed my suspicions that it had something to do with a conflict somewhere.

Here is a test page which has both slideshows on it, functioning with the sloppy transitions.

http://www.hauserair.com/slideshow-test/

I have narrowed it down to a  include of the following stylesheet.

http://www.hauserair.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/style.css?ver=1.0

When removing that  the slideshows transition properly.  Further more, when creating a standalone HTML file and including the bootstrap CSS and java files, and the necessary files for the new slider on this page: http://www.hauserair.com/slideshow.html

The transition problem re-occurs.  So... narrowing down this conflict...

In the aforementioned stylesheet, at the very bottom is the comment /* UPRIGHT STYLES */  These are custom styles that my company has wrote, after removing the code from beneath that comment, the problem persists.  So it is in fact inside the bootstrap code.

From there I can further deduce that no line of code that has an ID or a CLASS referenced in it should affect the slideshow, as the standalone .HTML file I made for testing does not have any of these ID's or Classes.  The exception to that is if there happens to be an identical rule for both `.flexslider` and `.home-slides`  (these are the classes assigned to the containers of the div's which contain the image sliders).

As the file does not contain any of those, I now can not seem to locate the particular line that could potentially be causing this transition issue.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following rule in */wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/style.css* on line 48

```
* {
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Remove or overwrite the transition rule on your slides and it should be fixed.

Comment: YES.  I can't believe I bloody missed that!  Thank you!  I have to wait 4 mins until I can checkmark it.